# discord.py when creating group gives AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

I was trying to make a discord bot that can do reddit functions. I decided to make it a group with a help function, and a co-group with a co-function.

```
# reddit group commands
@function_debug
@bot.group(pass_context = True)
async def reddit(context):
    message = context.message
    logger.debug(message.content)
    try:
        if message.server.name == 'PeaceCrafters' and message.channel.name == 'utilbots':
            cont = True
        elif message.server.name != 'PeaceCrafters':
            cont = True
        else:
            cont = False
    except AttributeError:
        cont = True
    finally:
        if cont:
            if context.invoked_subcommand is None:
                await reddit_help()


@function_debug
@reddit.command(name = 'help', description = 'Provides help with reddit', pass_context = True)
async def reddit_help(context):
    message = context.message
    logger.debug(message.content)
    try:
        if message.server.name == 'PeaceCrafters' and message.channel.name == 'utilbots':
            cont = True
        elif message.server.name != 'PeaceCrafters':
            cont = True
        else:
            cont = False
    except AttributeError:
        cont = True
    finally:
        if cont:
            message = reddit_message
            await bot.say(message)


@function_debug
@reddit.group(pass_context = True)
async def subreddit(context):
    message = context.message
    logger.debug(message.content)
    try:
        if message.server.name == 'PeaceCrafters' and message.channel.name == 'utilbots':
            cont = True
        elif message.server.name != 'PeaceCrafters':
            cont = True
        else:
            cont = False
    except AttributeError:
        cont = True
    finally:
        if cont:
            info = message.content.split(' ')[1:]
            subreddit = info[0]

@function_debug
@subreddit.command(name = 'hot', description = 'Lists the hot commands in the subreddit', pass_context = True)
async def subreddit_hot(context):
    message = context.message
    logger.debug(message.content)
    try:
        if message.server.name == 'PeaceCrafters' and message.channel.name == 'utilbots':
            cont = True
        elif message.server.name != 'PeaceCrafters':
            cont = True
        else:
            cont = False
    except AttributeError:
        cont = True
    finally:
        if cont:
            pass #i will add more once i figure out how message.content is handled
```

However, whenever I run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*/main.py", line 447, in <module>
    @reddit.group(name = 'reddit', pass_context=True)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'group'
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000223C92FFEF0>
```

I looked online at how other people coded their groups, and according to it my code should be valid. Why am I getting that error?

Comment: What discord.py version are you using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your `@function_debug` decorator is returning a `function`, not a `group`.  Rewrite the decorator to return a coroutine and switch the order of the decorators.

```
@bot.group(pass_context = True)
@function_debug
```